# Update Tkinter GUI while in outside loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have my code set up to print out to console it's progress as it loops through a few thousand items. This works perfectly well until I go to package it up and distribute it to others as there is no longer a console. My current method works, but the GUI consistently hangs after a few iterations while the loop continues to run.

The example code below runs, but my loops are much more complicated and hang up. I'm curious if there is a better way to accomplish this as I love using these GUI's but I have yet been able to find a good way of sending data to the GUI while I'm in a different loop.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

def do_loop(num_cycles):
    for i in range(0, int(num_cycles)):
        time.sleep(.25)
        # print(i)
        GUI_MSG.set(str(i))
        Tk.update_idletasks(FORM)

FORM = Tk()
GUI_MSG = StringVar()
FORM.wm_title('Perform Element Analysis')

IO_FRAME = LabelFrame(FORM, text=' Input/Output Directories ')
IO_FRAME.grid(row=0, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

Label(IO_FRAME, text="Numer of Loops").grid(
    row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=(10, 2), sticky='E')
NUMBER_LOOPS = Entry(IO_FRAME, width=10)
NUMBER_LOOPS.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=4)

Button(FORM, text='Generate Tables', command=lambda: do_loop(
    NUMBER_LOOPS.get())).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5)

Label(FORM, textvariable=GUI_MSG).grid(row=2, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=20)

FORM.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
time.sleep()
```

Sleep freezes the tkinter GUI, such that you cannot carry out any other action out on the GUI while it is running. As is stated in the python doc(https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)

> Suspend execution of the calling thread for the given number of seconds

You will be better served, considering your desired output to use

```
.after()
```

And you really might not need update_idletasks(). See if this works for you:

```
 from tkinter import *

class myFormWindow():
   def __init__(self,FORM):
      self.count=0
      self.GUI_MSG = StringVar()
      self.FORM=FORM
      self.FORM.wm_title('Perform Element Analysis')

      IO_FRAME = LabelFrame(self.FORM, text=' Input/Output Directories ')
      IO_FRAME.grid(row=0, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

      Label(IO_FRAME, text="Numer of Loops").grid(
      row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=(10, 2), sticky='E')
      self.NUMBER_LOOPS = Entry(IO_FRAME, width=10)
      self.NUMBER_LOOPS.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=4)
      Button(self.FORM, text='Generate Tables', command=self.get_cycles).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5)
      Label(self.FORM, textvariable=self.GUI_MSG).grid(row=2, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=20)



   def get_cycles(self):
      self.num_cycles=self.NUMBER_LOOPS.get()
      self.do_loop()

   def do_loop(self):
       if self.count<int(self.num_cycles):
       self.GUI_MSG.set(str(self.count))
       self.count+=1
       self.FORM.after(1000,self.do_loop)


if __name__=="__main__":
   FORM=Tk()
   form_window=myFormWindow(FORM)
   FORM.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works, but ideally the loop would work outside of the class. As I said I have quite an extensive set of functions that don't make sense to be wrapped up in the GUI class. Also the sleep was just used for the example. 
Specifically what my code does is it uses a GUI for the user to select a set of data as inputs, it uses these inputs to create a fracture analysis input file then it runs the fracture analysis program using os.system(frac_analysis.exe <inputfile> <options>). After the exe is run the code then parses the resultant file then goes on to run the next file in the list.

Comment: great, sorry I did not follow your desired behaviour. `.after()` can be used to call functions outside your class. You will need to rearrange the code to suit you desired behaviour. This NMT doc [after doc](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Following the initial logic of your question and using `.after()` to reference outside of a function:

```
from tkinter import *

def do_loop():
     global count,num_cycles,GUI_MSG
     if count<int(num_cycles):
         GUI_MSG.set(str(count))
         count+=1
         FORM.after(1000,do_loop)

def get_cycles():
     global num_cycles
     num_cycles=NUMBER_LOOPS.get()
     do_loop()

count=0    
FORM = Tk()
GUI_MSG = StringVar()
FORM.wm_title('Perform Element Analysis')

IO_FRAME = LabelFrame(FORM, text=' Input/Output Directories ')
IO_FRAME.grid(row=0, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

Label(IO_FRAME, text="Numer of Loops").grid(
row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=(10, 2), sticky='E')
NUMBER_LOOPS = Entry(IO_FRAME, width=10)
NUMBER_LOOPS.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=4)

Button(FORM, text='Generate Tables', command=get_cycles).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5)

Label(FORM, textvariable=GUI_MSG).grid(row=2, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=20)

FORM.mainloop()
```